# How to augment methods during ByteBuddy transformation?

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy, bytecode-manipulation

### Context

I am implementing byte code transformations with ByteBuddy and the process of manipulation is a multi step process.
Because of that, the manipulation has to be able to:

1. augment originally existing methods
2. create new methods entirely
3. augment a method that was introduced via 2.

For 1. I used an `@OnMethodExit` advice applied via:

```
Builder<?> builder = builder.visit(Advice.to(Helper.class)
  .on(ElementMatchers.hasMethodNamed(name));
```

with `Helper` the augmentation code for the method (effectively setting a field's value).
When creating new methods, I build them as follows:

```
Builder<?> builder = builder.defineMethod(…)
  .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(OtherHelper.class));
  .…;
```

`OtherHelper` consumes the runtime instance via a static method taking `@This Object object` as argument.

### The problem

In short: I don't see the *former* transformation applied if it follows the latter.
The actual execution order is as follows:

1. My type gets processed and a method added via `MethodDelegation.…`.
2. In a subsequent step I find that newly introduced method and try to augment the implementation generation through `Advice.to(…)` using an `@OnMethodExit` advice.
3. The resulting code has the behavior of step 1 but is lacking the behavior of step 2.

I am assuming I invalidly combine the two parts of the implementation. Any ideas? A hunch: does the `ElementMatcher` matching the augmentation by name not see the method introduced using `….defineMethod(…)` yet? The `name` is coming from some method inspection I start from `builder.toTypeDescription()` which actually makes me assume that the to-be-created method is already visible to the builder as otherwise it wouldn't be found in that step in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share a reconstruction of your example? In a simple example, I observe the expected behavior:

```
public class Bar {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<?> type = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class)
      .visit(Advice.to(Bar.class).on(named("m")))
      .defineMethod("m", void.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
      .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Bar.class))
      .make()
      .load(Bar.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
      .getLoaded();

    type.getMethod("m").invoke(type.getConstructor().newInstance());
  }

  @BindingPriority(2)
  public static void delegation() {
    System.out.println("Delegation!");
  }

  @Advice.OnMethodEnter
  public static void enter() {
    System.out.println("Advice!");
  }
}
```

This example prints both *Advice!* and *Delegation!*.

Comment: Pretty embarrassing. I have an advice to init a boolean field to `true` and reused that when I actually want the method to be intercepted to flip that flag to `false`. My tests *of course* saw that flag still being `true`. ‍♂️ SO everything works as expected. Thanks for the sample, that actually made me realize my (rather stupid) mistake.

Comment: That's what SO is here for! Glad you figured it out!